# Omit properties with of certain types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am working on a simple project for school. And I am wondering if it's possible to omit all properties of certain type in TypeScript.

```
type Student = {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    age: number
    gender: Gender
    courses: List<Course>
}
```

So In this case I just want a type with everything from Student without *"courses"*.

**Is it possible to generate a Type** which is Student but without all the properties that has a List type? It needs to be generic so it works on all types for example:

```
type Program = {
    name: string
    errors: List<Error>
    successes: List<Success>
    warnings: List<Warning>
}
```

Now it would give a type which just contains { name: string }

Does anyone know how to do this, if it is even possible? Maybe with conditional types? Omit if List?

All the help is much appreciated!

**Update: add code example:**

```
type WithoutList<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends List<any> ? never : T[K]
}

const select = <a, b extends keyof WithoutList<a>>(arg: a, ...keys: b[]) => {
    return null!
}

const s1: Student = {
    firstName: 's',
    lastName: 's',
    age: 22,
    gender: 'female',
    courses: List<Course>(),
}

select(s1, 'courses') // courses should not be available here!
```

Comment: `type OmitLists<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends List<any> ? never : T[P] };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) to map all the *keys* you want to suppress to `never`:

```
type WithoutList<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends List<any> ? never : K]: T[K]
};
```

You can verify that this works for the `Student` and `Program` types from your example:

```
type StudentWithoutList = WithoutList<Student>;
/* type StudentWithoutList = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    age: number;
    gender: Gender;
} */

type ProgramWithoutList = WithoutList<Program>;
/* type ProgramWithoutList = {
    name: string;
} */
```

as well as desired behavior for your `select()` function:

```
declare const s1: Student;
select(s1, "age"); // okay
select(s1, 'courses') // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDLAM5gDwBUB8yA3gFDLIBucANgFzK4A0ZyIEAHmAPz3pZ74SAXxIlQkWIhQBlAK4IkGDMRYALAPbqocAJ70wUWRADcwseGjwkyAOpwoIUAHMV5BHFlhg6kPsMmzMB0ABxQAcQgQABNoZABeZAAiAFsaCETkAB8kmAhU6nSspPUwVWhE03MJKxQAYXVZKAwUUnIAdw0AaRB1Nox6LChnUxESINDkaTBZGPB412QYYCawADk4ZIgBg2cWajgsdc3toZAnFjgnLdZZZIAjaBYr6Oh6CJeoFgQGpoh+tEwOHqjWaglG4xQAAUoOonNpkvNWqwNtdBrtyNAYU1eIDsABRKBYwTkDDyRTNf58HByBR-DDE5BteyOM6U3F2BzOMGiMYhFA2YClBpgKkCREsADanWQoGQAGsIDp1DAGMgDgwpQBdZAcSDRZSiuAgHSELisCAUWL0Tqa+i4LXCSoQ5DQ2HwgVCzxU+YejRe3GuuEbfCmAD0ACpkM7A+7BX6RYDxeRyCAUSdhsJkOHQ6JnVMZpEwL7hd6EsX-fx87MwCGSBGo3zJtNq+WE1gk8mlisjqidmdTMnkPtDmnkGj+yxyJdriBbg8oAPk88YlA3pEVyMszmSN8QO3mgUEGB5tgAIKMZAAIR1nHXygVSpVrdFp-w+AAFPYnPRz8gAHQAQ+-yXhKmoAJTxIQSJQBA0wODc1DUAAhGYJAxAg+wwcgu77gAjPQVaFqYB4QEe74YLhF6JNOiRgcYyChqGyDqHKugkCRZEUReADk3wgn83EQYxOqEloSFAA)

Comment: Damn! This works for me, thanks man! I still need to practice a lot I see, but I've learned a lot from your answer!

Answer (score 1):

A [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) combined with a conditional type that evaluates to `never` when the type extends `List` will get what you want.

Since `Gender`, `List`, and `Course` aren't defined in your code, I'll use `Array` and primitive types instead for illustration:

```
type Student = {
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
    age: number
    courses: Array<string>
}

type WithoutList<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<any> ? never : T[K]
}

type StudentWithoutCourse = WithoutList<Student>;
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=50#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCuATCA7YUC8UDeAoKBUAZgJYBOAzsAHICGAthAFxRVkkoDm+hANrVTqMWbDt0JRanZlBTx6AIwhkeBAMYB7eJQgUWAQTJlaIADyiuAPlwBfXLlCQoAdRLAAFluAAZElVMAKpaYOKpQANoA0lAcUADWECAaRFABALosAVFpUBAAHsCoiBRQhsZmtCggwQD8shAAbspQmdm29o7QcEiowK4eXgDCWjoh-Z7wPn7Apt3IaJYA3EA)

Comment: It's not exactly what I mean. I will add some code to my question. With a select method. It should have access to all but courses. But with your custom type it is still a property you can select.